# C# display images and text in list

Tags: c#, listview

Is there any control in c# which allows us to make some sort of list view with images and formatted text and icons, something like the contacts in android? The closest I found is this:

1) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/ListViewInCSharp11172005021741AM/ListViewInCSharp.aspx

2) http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/75911-adding-images-to-listview/

Which in my opinion is very ugly compared to what android and iPhone can do, something like this:

```
http://www.trymasak.my/sample/iphone2.jpg
```

Comment: Can you modify your tags?  Are you using winforms?  wpf?  silverlight?

Comment: actually i'm not sure.. i just use visual studio 2010. noob in this thing, i am.

Comment: @imin You don't know what kind if application you are building?!

Comment: actually i'm trying to create an application which would run on intel tablet running windows 7..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, well if you don't care whether you use WinForms or WPF, I would recommend using WPF.

If you want something like a `ListView`, try using the `DataGrid`.  The basic concept you need here is the usage of the `DataTemplate`.  Within the `DataTemplate`, you can restyle the contents of the cell however you like.

Here's a rough example that I pulled from some of my code, but I haven't made it compile on its own.  It'll give you a good head start.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyGridData}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="my_datagrid">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Column1">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source={Binding GridCellImage}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding GridCellText}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Read up on databinding to understand `MyGridData`.  It's basically going to be a collection in code-behind that supplies the information for your grid.  It could be something like a `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>`.  T is a class that has two public properties called `GridCellImage` and `GridCellText`.  WPF makes it easy in that you create your data in code-behind, and because it is databound your GUI will update automatically (in the case of the `ObservableCollection`).  Set `GridCellImage` to your image path and `GridCellText` to the text you want in that cell.  `GridCellImage` needs more specified to actually make it work, but the point of this answer is to show you how easy it is to retemplate stuff in WPF to make it display data pretty much however you like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: not a really accurate answer to my problem, but it points me to the right direction.. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying but a lot of times getting something to 'work' and 'styling' are two very, very different things. It also largely depends on what technology you are using: WinForms (probably the simplest to get started with, though customization can be a big chore), WPF, Silverlight, the list goes on.

Here is something I stumbled upon. It's fairly recent, too. I'm pretty sure it would help get jump-started in WinForms. It's called ObjectListView:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16009/A-Much-Easier-to-Use-ListView

Answer (score 0):

USe wpf Project. Create either StackPanel or Dockpanel and then add your components in it.

Then add this panel to child of your Grid View